# print branch taken or not in qemu plugin

Tags: qemu

How to print  `branch taken/not taken if branch instruction` in the qemu execlog plugin?

`api.c` does have a `get_ms` option but on using it it shows the error:

> undefined symbol: get_ms

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried so far? There seems to be a decent number of results for similar queries online. Have you checked any of these?

Comment: I was understanding the functions of plugins from the official docs but couldn't find a way to do this. Could you please share the online queries you mentioned? @music2myear